# multidimentional char array - how to fill it with random chars?

Tags: c++, random, char, generator

So I have tried to create a generator like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
char* data;
void genRandomFilledChar(char *s, int i, int j, int k) { 
    const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int q = 0; q < i; ++q) {
        for (int w = 0; w < j; ++w) {
            for (int e = 0; e < k; ++e) {
                s[e] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
            }
        } }}

int main()
{
    data =  new char[10000][10000][10000];
    genRandomFilledChar(data, 10000, 10000, 10000);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give us the compiler error please.

Comment: that's a pretty big array you got there.

Comment: Maybe our [FAQ on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664) will clear some things up for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* data;
// ....
data =  new char[10000][10000][10000];
```

Are wrong. First, a three dimensional array of chars is `char***`. Next, you need to initialize that memory in 3 steps.

```
data = new char**[10000];
for(int i=0; i < 10000; ++i){
  data[i] = new char*[10000];
  for(int j=0; j < 10000; ++j){
    data[i][j] = new char[10000];
    for(int k=0; k < 10000; ++k){
      // and for best performance, initialize directly
      data[i][j][k] = /*HERE*/;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not work like it should. You create new `data` pointer 10000 times and reassign it every time. Also you didn't fill `*data` and `**data` correctly, you have lost `i` and `j`. Please, fix your code.

Comment: @DReJ: Oh my god, now that was embarassing, must be the lack of sleep. Thanks for pointing the errors out. >_>"

Comment: Multidimensional arrays and nested pointers are not the same thing at all, see our [FAQ on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can't allocate new array like you do. You should declare one dimensional array of proper size or create array of pointers to pointer to array.

```
char *data = new char [1000*1000*1000];
```

or

```
char ***data = new char**[1000];
for (int i=0; i< 1000; i++) {
    data[i] = new char*[1000];
    for (int j=0; j< 1000; j++) {
        data[i][j] = new char[1000];
    }
}
```

Also you have error in `genRandomFilledChar`. You fill only first 10000 chars with random values every time.

And, the last. For `rand()` you need to initialize random generator with `srand`.

Comment: Yes we can: `char (*data)[1000][1000] = new char[1000][1000][1000];`

Answer (score 1):

```
s[e] = alphanum[rand % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
```

should be

```
s[q][w][e] = alphanum[rand % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
```

because it is a 3 dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

Because `new char[10000][10000][10000]` has the type `char (*)[10000][10000]`, not `char*`, the type of `data`. And I think what you want is

```
void genRandomFilledChar(char *s, int i, int j, int k) { 
    const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int q = 0; q < i; ++q) {
        for (int w = 0; w < j; ++w) {
            for (int e = 0; e < k; ++e) {
                s[e + w * k + q * j * k] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    data =  new char[10000 * 10000 * 10000];
    genRandomFilledChar(data, 10000, 10000, 10000);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained the `-1` ;)

Answer (score 1):

C multidimensional arrays are just a way to calculate index automatically.
Why not declare char data[i*j*k] (or get from heap with new) and then fill it as if it is single dimension? You can later use [][][] indexes with data.